# I have a question when I use oracle query

Tags: oracle, date

Good morning, why I have this error when I run this query?

```
select  to_char( TO_CHAR(to_date('01/09/2018'),'MM')||
      INITCAP(SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (to_date('01/09/2018'), 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = SPANISH'),
                      1,
                      3
              ))        
      || '/'
      || to_char(trunc((to_date('01/09/2018')-next_day(trunc(to_date('01/09/2018'),'DY')-8, 'Mon'))/7 )+1))from dual
```

> ORA-01846: day of the week not valid

Thanks

Comment: I found my error i had to write "lunes" instead of "mon"

Comment: `TO_CHAR(to_date('01/09/2018'),'MM')` can be simplified to `'09'` or maybe `'01'` depending on your NLS settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edwin:

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If you are using Spanish, you might consider this change from "mon" to "lunes"

```
select  to_char( TO_CHAR(to_date('01/09/2018'),'MM')||
      INITCAP(SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (to_date('01/09/2018'), 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = SPANISH'),
                      1,
                      3
              ))        
      || '/'
      || to_char(trunc((to_date('01/09/2018')-next_day(trunc(to_date('01/09/2018'),'DY')-8, 'Lunes'))/7 )+1))from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select to_Char(to_date('01/09/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM') from dual;
```